# find and findOne in indexedDB

Tags: javascript, angularjs, indexeddb

I understand indexedDB doesn't have findOne or find functions (as MongoDB does), but what I want to accomplish is similar to those functions.

I have a data store in indexedDB. I created an index on the store using, say, the `stop_id`.

I want to find, in the store, all documents with the `stop_id`. Multiple objects might have one `stop_id` value.

**What I have:**

I am trying to cheat a bit (please correct me if there's a better way)

```
// this function is called from html via angularjs
    $scope.findOne = function(stop_id) {
        var db;
        var request = indexedDB.open("Trans");
        request.onerror = function(event) {
            alert("Couldn't connect to Database");
        };
        request.onsuccess = function(event) {
            db = event.target.result;
            var objectStore = db.transaction("times").objectStore("times");
            var index = objectStore.index("stop_id");

            var range = IDBKeyRange.only(stop_id);

            // call something here to retrieve
            // One or All documents with the ID of stop_id
            // passed in from the html
        }
    }
```

I would then want to call in html as so:

```
    <div class="medium-6 columns" ng-repeat="stops in objects | orderBy: 'stop_name'">
        <div class="card hoverable">
            <div class="content">
                <span class="title">{{stops.stop_name}}</span><small class="float-right">{{stops.stop_id}}</small>
                <!-- this function will search another object store, then retrieve all documents matching the stop_id -->
                {{ findOne(stops.stop_id)}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am considering the above approach because indexedDB doesn't support joins natively, and I will want to use native indexeddb workarounds to achieve retrieving extra data relating to an id in another datastore on the fly. Performance isn't a concern. Both Data store documents wont be more than 150 items.

Answer (score 0):

Use the IDBIndex get or openCursor method.

```
// for one
var range = IDBKeyRange.only(myId);
var getRequest = index.get(range);
getRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
  var result = event.target.result;
  console.log(result);
};

// for multiple ...
var getRequest = index.openCursor(range);
var documentsFound = [];
getRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
  var request = event.target;
  var cursor = request.result;
  if(!cursor) {
    console.log('no match found, or no more matches found');
    someFunction(documentsFound);
  } else {
    console.log('Found:', cursor.value);
    documentsFound.push(cursor.value);
    cursor.advance();
  }
};
```

If multiple objects in the store can have the same `stop_id`, then make sure you do not use a `unique:true` flag when creating the index in your onupgradeneeded handler.

Comment: Thanks. Will give it a try. And yes, I didn't create a unique:true index on them

Comment: Not working as I expected. I get a bunch of repeating undistinct results in console. From the onset, I don't know whether a query will result in multiple objects or not, so I went wi the multiple option above. I am probably not doing something right. Will appreciate more clarification to help me get this whole indexeddb thing.

Comment: The section that iterates multiple records above will never return the same object twice, but it could potentially return objects that appear similar. It just lists all objects with the given stop_id parameter. I showed an example of shoving the matching stops into an array. Maybe you're not resetting the array between calls or something like that?